# A trigger that fires another trigger loop

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL trigger on an insert to table A that inserts a row in table B and an insert on table B that inserts a row on table A.
The problem is they are firing each other in an endless loop, which the MySQL stops, since it isn't allowed.

How can I tell if I the insert is triggered from the other trigger and not do it?

Comment: maybe give him a suggestion on how to change the database in stead of just bashing him..?

Comment: Dirty solution: You could set up a flag somewhere in your db, set it true when table A fires, Only let B insert something if the flag is true and set it to false.

Comment: [How to avoid circular Trigger dependencies in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570204/how-to-avoid-circular-trigger-dependencies-in-mysql)