# What are Circular Triggers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm a noob.

I was wondering if someone could give me an overview of what Circular Triggers are.

When I search for it, I see people talking about them and trying to avoid them, but I would like to see an example of a circular trigger actually happening.

Like I said, I'm a noob and I apologize.  This is into is needed for something I'm doing with work.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid circular Trigger dependencies in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570204/how-to-avoid-circular-trigger-dependencies-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

A circular trigger is a trigger that triggers itself, causing an endless loop.

**Example**
[Nested AFTER Triggers in SQL Server](http://blog.dbandbi.com/tag/what-is-nested-trigger-in-sql-server/)

> Nested AFTER Triggers in SQL Server are AFTER triggers nested to each
>   other or a trigger on table1 could affect table2 and a trigger on
>   table2 could affect table1 recursively. This circular execution will
>   go till it reaches its maximum depth of 32 then it will stop.

Comment: I looked at the example.  Do you actually need two triggers to pull this off?